# Is it possible to disable ext4 case sensitivity?

Tags: linux, ext4, case-sensitivity

With NTFS you can enable or disable case sensitivity. Is there a way to do it with ext4 in Linux?

Comment: I don't know too much about NTFS, but you can't do that with ext4, there is no known driver for that. Your question seems to be X-Y.

Comment: this would cause random breakages (as seen on macOS which stuck case sensitive unix conventions onto the case insensitive HFS) as some software will have a `Makefile` but build a temporary `makefile`, or so forth

Comment: @炸鱼薯条德里克 you can do that with ext4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are patches currently under development to implement case insensitivity for ext4.

https://lwn.net/Articles/762826/
https://marc.info/?l=linux-ext4&m=154430575726827&w=2

They were included in the Linux 5.2 kernel, and also require e2fsprogs-1.45 to work. See [How to enable new in kernel 5.2 case-insensitivity for ext4 on a given directory?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/558977/how-to-enable-new-in-kernel-5-2-case-insensitivity-for-ext4-on-a-given-directory)

Comment: Also interesting to look at the article from LWN on the subject for a nice overview: https://lwn.net/Articles/772960/

Comment: Looks like those [went in](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/558977).

Answer (score 2):

Nope. Under linux you can do that to fat,vfat,hpfs,ntfs and to iso9660 w/ rockridge extensions. All linux (unix) native file systems I know are case-sensitive.

Comment: `All linux (unix) native file systems I know are case-sensitive.` there are lots of Unix file systems that support case-insensitive file names like Btrfs, ZFS, Reiserfs, XFS, HFS+... and now ext4