# How to enable new in kernel 5.2 case-insensitivity for ext4 on a given directory?

Tags: linux, ext4, case-sensitivity

I saw that kernel 5.2 got handling of ext4 case-insensitivity per directory by flipping a `+F` bit in inode.

> This EXT4 case-insensitive file-name lookup feature works on a
>   per-directory basis when an empty directory is enabled by flipping the
>   +F inode attribute.

https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=EXT4-Case-Insensitive-Linux-5.2

But how to do that? Does any chmod handle that? My distributions doesn't look like it.

So how do I use this feature?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First you need recent enough software:

- [Linux kernel >= 5.2](https://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_5.2#Optional_support_for_case-insensitive_names_in_ext4) for the kernel-side support in EXT4
- userland tools: [e2fsprogs >= 1.45](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/ext4.5.html#KERNEL_SUPPORT) (eg: on Debian 10 which ships only version 1.44 this requires [buster-backports](https://backports.debian.org/news/buster-backports/)). Provides among others [`mke2fs`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mke2fs.8.html) (alias `mkfs.ext4`), [`tune2fs`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/tune2fs.8.html) and [`chattr`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chattr.1.html).
- **UPDATE**:

  - e2fsprogs >= 1.45.7 needed to [allow enabling *casefold*](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/fs/ext2/e2fsprogs.git/commit/?id=1f9bb778a8e693f8d5f2fd7a26fd6b9fe2e3212a) using `tune2fs` on an unmounted filesystem after it was created without it.
  - e2fsprogs >= 1.46.6 needed to [allow *disabling* *casefold*](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/fs/ext2/e2fsprogs.git/commit/?id=47f9c3c00bbfdef4a64f400d1c95d9140aab3199) using `tune2fs` after it was enabled, and only if no directory still has the `+F`flag.
  - to also use filesystem encryption, this [requires](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/commit/?id=471fbbea7ff7061b2d6474665cb5a2ceb4fd6500) [Linux kernel >= 5.13](https://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_5.13#File_systems).

With this installed, the documentation from [`man ext4`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/ext4.5.html#KERNEL_SUPPORT) does reflect the existence of this feature:

> **casefold**
>
> This ext4 feature provides file system level character encoding support for directories with the **casefold (+F) flag** enabled. This
> feature is name-preserving on the disk, but it allows applications to
> lookup for a file in the file system using an encoding equivalent
> version of the file name.

The *casefold* feature must first be enabled as a filesystem-wide ext4 option. <s>Sadly, I couldn't manage to enable it on an already formatted filesystem</s>. So using a sparse file created with `dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/image.raw bs=1 count=1 seek=$((2**32-1))` to test on a newly created filesystem.

```
# tune2fs -O casefold /tmp/image.raw 
tune2fs 1.45.3 (14-Jul-2019)
Setting filesystem feature 'casefold' not supported.
#
```

**UPDATE**: Since [this commit](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/fs/ext2/e2fsprogs.git/commit/?id=1f9bb778a8e693f8d5f2fd7a26fd6b9fe2e3212a) it's possible to use `tune2fs` to enable *casefold* on an unmounted filesystem. When this answer was written this feature was not yet available:

```
# tune2fs -O casefold /tmp/image.raw
tune2fs 1.47.0 (5-Feb-2023)
#
```

So when formatting, this will enable the feature:

```
# mkfs.ext4 -O casefold /tmp/image.raw
```

or to specify an other encoding rather than default (*utf8*). It appears that currently [there is only *utf8-12.1*](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/fs/ext2/e2fsprogs.git/tree/lib/e2p/encoding.c?h=v1.45.4#n30), of which *utf8* is an alias anyway:

```
# mkfs.ext4 -E encoding=utf8-12.1 /tmp/image.raw
```

You can verify what was done with tune2fs:

```
# tune2fs -l /tmp/image.raw |egrep 'features|encoding'
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype extent 64bit flex_bg casefold sparse_super large_file huge_file dir_nlink extra_isize metadata_csum
Character encoding:       utf8-12.1
```

Now to use the feature:

```
# mount -o loop /tmp/image.raw /mnt
# mkdir /mnt/caseinsensitivedir
# chattr +F /mnt/caseinsensitivedir
# touch /mnt/caseinsensitivedir/camelCaseFile
# ls /mnt/caseinsensitivedir/
camelCaseFile
# ls /mnt/caseinsensitivedir/camelcasefile
/mnt/caseinsensitivedir/camelcasefile
# mv /mnt/caseinsensitivedir/camelcasefile /mnt/caseinsensitivedir/Camelcasefile
mv: '/mnt/caseinsensitivedir/camelcasefile' and '/mnt/caseinsensitivedir/Camelcasefile' are the same file
```